# The use of setFrameRange method

Tags: qt, animation, graphics

What is the use of setFrameRange method (which is a part of QTimeLine class)? I found this example:

```
QGraphicsItem *ball = new QGraphicsEllipseItem(0, 0, 20, 20);

 QTimeLine *timer = new QTimeLine(5000);
 timer->setFrameRange(0, 100);

 QGraphicsItemAnimation *animation = new QGraphicsItemAnimation;
 animation->setItem(ball);
 animation->setTimeLine(timer);

 for (int i = 0; i < 200; ++i)
     animation->setPosAt(i / 200.0, QPointF(i, i));

 QGraphicsScene *scene = new QGraphicsScene();
 scene->setSceneRect(0, 0, 250, 250);
 scene->addItem(ball);

 QGraphicsView *view = new QGraphicsView(scene);
 view->show();

 timer->start();
```

Obviously everything seems to work well but I noticed that modifying this parameter doesn't change a thing. I tried to write sth like this:

- timer->setFrameRange(100, 100)
- timer->setFrameRage(0,0)

but despite of what I'm doing the result is still the same.

To sum everything up, I have two questions. What is this method doing (and yes, I've read the documentation), and why my modifications doesn't change anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've read the documentation, you'll have noticed that it states that it can be used for calling currentFrame() or frameForTime(). Therefore, it sets a relationship of the timeline to frames. As you're not calling either of those functions, it's doing nothing!

I would guess that by setting the frame from 0 to 100, it means that asking for the current frame at 2.5 seconds (with a time line of 5000), you would get back 50, whereas setting the start and end frame as 0 - 50, you would get back 25. This is also going to be related to calling frameChanged(int frame) if you're interested in getting notified when a particular frame has been reached.

To summarise, it allows reference to the animation in frames, using interpolation between the minimum and maximum values you want to use.